# Изменение представления даты

Tags: python, datetime

У меня есть дата `2021-10-14` в типе данных `datetime`. Как мне поменять из данного представления даты в `14-10-2021` ?

Comment: хранится дата и время в совсем другом виде. то, что вы привели: `2021-10-14` и `14-10-2021` — это лишь формат отображения. подобные вопросы многократно здесь задавались. знатоки python! подскажите автору вопроса подходящие дубликаты.

Answer (score 1):

вам вот это нужно?

```
import datetime

date = datetime.datetime.now()

print(date.strftime("%d-%m-%Y"))
```

а получить по произвольному формату из строки можно так:

```
date = datetime.datetime.strptime("22+11+2021", "%d+%m+%Y")
```

Comment: А так чтобы дата оставалась в типе данных datetime?

Comment: внутри `datetime` дата хранится в своем формате, о котором у вас вообще голова не должна болеть, для вас это черный ящик, для вас важно в каком формате вводить дату (я добавил код ниже в ответе) и в каком формате выводить дату

Comment: Вы очень противный

Comment: @denikotin Чем раньше вы поймёте, что речь может идти только о форматах ввода-вывода даты, тем лучше. То, как дата хранится в своём родном типе поменять вы никак не можете, и видеть про тип дата можете только то, что он показывает наружу при печати и т.д.

Comment: @Zhihar, возможно, аатор вопроса хотел бы изменить умолчальный формат, который используется при вызове функции `print(date)`. например, чтоб не заморачиваться каждый раз с преобразованиями в нужный вид.